# Can you finish() an activity from an object?

Tags: android, activity-finish

I have a class that represents my activity and a have an object that look like

```
  public class main extends Activity{
  //Does stuff
  }

  public class Object{
  //I want to call finish() here
  }
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Your design is a bit odd. How will the object pass the signal? To a static field? Why is an object that has no relation to an Activity trying to finish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Object have a constructor accepting an Activity parameter, and pass in your activity instance when you instantiate your Object class.

Example:

```
class MyObject {
    private Activity act;
    public Object(Activity act) { this.act = act;}

    public doStuff() {
        // do stuff
        act.finish();
    }
}

//usage in some code inside your activity:
MyObject obj = new MyObject(this);
obj->doStuff();
```

Comment: I don't use this object in the activity, so that may prove difficult. I think the easiest way to solve this is by using a while loop and an if statement to call finish only when the object sends a signal via boolean flag. I was hoping there was a better alternative.

Comment: Your design is a bit odd. How will the object pass the signal? To a static field? Why is an object that has no relation to an Activity trying to finish it? If the object is residing inside the activity you can just call `main.this.finish();` from within the object.

Comment: @Tomislav: 1st and 2nd questions: no need to signal. 3rd question: that's a question to ask the OP. 4th: you can do that if Object is an inner class of the activity, that's not what the OP showed.